# How to tell if a github reference is a commit hash, a branch name or a tag?

Tags: git, github

Git references, e.g. those used in `git://` uris in NPM packages or the `/tarball` route in github, can come in (at least) three forms: branch names, commit hashes, or tag names. Is there a route in the GitHub api to be able to determine, given an arbitrary reference, which type it is? The only way I can think of to do it is to attempt to hit the `/tags`, `/branches` and `/commits` routes with the reference, waiting for one of them to return a successful result. Of course, this is not very efficient. Is there a better way?

Even better would be a route that, given one of these types of references, would convert it into a commit hash (so given a commit hash it would return the hash; given a branch it would return the latest commit on the branch, and given a tag it would return the commit hash that tag points to).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. If you have a commit hash, you can use the `/tree` endpoint:

```
https://github.com/owner/repo/tree/commit-hash
```

If you have an input string, you can check the different endpoints as you mentioned.

Currently GitHub doesn't have such a feature and will probably have not since you may have a branch and a tag with the same name (then it would occur a confusion between types).

Comment: The thing is that I don't know ahead of time whether I have a commit hash or not.

Comment: Well, if you have an input string, you can check the different endpoints as you mentioned. Such a feature doesn't exist. Think that you may have a branch name and a tag with the same name. Then how do you know which one to choose? The best solution is to use the GitHub API and check the different endpoints. :)

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing. Thanks :P

Comment: @limp_chimp You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the answer.